# How do we add facebookSDK into a xcode project using cmake?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, cmake

I am having some difficulties adding facebookSDK.framework into my xcode project using cmake?
Here's what i have done up to now. But it doesn't seem to work

```
set (facebook_sdk_path ${CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY}/external/framework/facebook/ios)
message("adding facebookSDK" ${facebook_sdk_path})
target_link_libraries(${Target} "${facebook_sdk_path}/facebookSDK.framework/facebookSDK")
```

I believe we need to set the framework under "framework search paths" on the project settings, but I am not exactly too sure on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my solution: i used this macro i found from [CMake and XCode: "cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473448/cmake-and-xcode-cannot-find-interface-declaration-for-nsobject)

```
macro(AddExternalFramework fwname appname libpath)
    find_library(FRAMEWORK_${fwname}
        NAMES ${fwname}
        PATHS ${libpath} 
        NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    if( ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}} STREQUAL FRAMEWORK_${fwname}-NOTFOUND)
        MESSAGE(ERROR ": Framework ${fwname} not found: ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}}")
    else()
        TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${appname} ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}})
        MESSAGE(STATUS "Framework ${fwname} found at ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}}")
    endif()
endmacro(AddExternalFramework)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but Frank's answer didn't work for me. As it was mentioned on the post referenced, calling `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` messes up the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` variable. In my case it finds **FacebookSDK.framework** but then generates linker errors for the rest of the frameworks included (e.g. UIKit, Foundation, etc.).

My solution was simply copying **FacebookSDK.framework** to the XCode frameworks folders. Bear in mind you need to copy it to both iPhoneOS and iPhoneSimulator if you build for device and simulator. Currently, XCode7 and SDK9.0, those folders are:

- `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`
- `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`

Adding **FacebookSDK.framework** as usual works fine then:

```
SET (OUR_FRAMEWORKS "-framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework FacebookSDK ...")
```