# Can't link MacOS frameworks with CMake

Tags: ios, frameworks, linker, cmake

I'm trying to build a subproject with cmake (it's **not** an xcode project or even an app for iphone, the result is cross-platform console executable, which #includes some inherited from C++ abstract classes, written in objective-c++)

I'm using this guide to link mac os frameworks: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:HowToUseExistingOSXFrameworks

and this macro:

```
macro(ADD_FRAMEWORK fwname appname)
find_library(FRAMEWORK_${fwname}
    NAMES ${fwname}
    PATHS ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library
    PATH_SUFFIXES Frameworks
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
if( ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}} STREQUAL FRAMEWORK_${fwname}-NOTFOUND)
    MESSAGE(ERROR ": Framework ${fwname} not found")
else()
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${appname} ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}})
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Framework ${fwname} found at ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}}")
endif()
endmacro(ADD_FRAMEWORK)
```

This is the important part in CMakeLists.txt

```
project(myprojectname)
........
add_executable(mytarget src/mytarget.cpp)

add_framework(CoreMedia mytarget)
add_framework(CoreVideo mytarget)
add_framework(AVFoundation mytarget)
add_framework(Foundation mytarget)
........
```

And that's what i have when trying to build:

```
WARNING: Target "mytarget" requests linking to directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "mytarget" requests linking to directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "mytarget" requests linking to directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "mytarget" requests linking to directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
```

It actually finds all these frameworks, but can't link, which produces a lot of linker errors. I'm pretty sure that that's the reason because i made a testproj using XCode and it has the same errors till i linked all the needed frameworks.

When i just use

```
FIND_LIBRARY(COREMEDIA_LIB CoreMedia)
...
```

then `COREMEDIA_LIB` is set to `NOTFOUND` - what's going on? :/

I googled a lot but nothing :( Feeling pretty much lost there.

Comment: Well, got it working with `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-framework fm1-framework fm2..."`

Why doesn't the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822404/how-to-set-up-cmake-to-build-an-app-for-the-iphone way work? (the answer with that macro i'm actually tried to use)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Got the thing: you have to link **NOT** the `frameworkname.framework` folder in the `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`, but the `fwname.framework/fwname` file! Now it works that way.

The changed macro is this:

```
macro(ADD_FRAMEWORK fwname appname)
    find_library(FRAMEWORK_${fwname}
    NAMES ${fwname}
    PATHS ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library
    PATH_SUFFIXES Frameworks
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    if( ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}} STREQUAL FRAMEWORK_${fwname}-NOTFOUND)
        MESSAGE(ERROR ": Framework ${fwname} not found")
    else()
        TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${appname} "${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}}/${fwname}")
        MESSAGE(STATUS "Framework ${fwname} found at ${FRAMEWORK_${fwname}}")
    endif()
endmacro(ADD_FRAMEWORK)
```

Hope it will be useful for someone...

Comment: This seems to add the frameworks in the "Other Linker Flags" AKA OTHER_LDFLAGS but it doesn't add anything to the header "Header Search Paths" AKA HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS so my code can't find UIKit/UIKit.h. Suggestions?

Comment: In my case, neither the OTHER_LDFLAGS are set (or, it seems they are set to empty values, since the lable in Xcode Build settings pane is bold.