# How can i create an Xcode project via command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake

I've to automatize the creation of a **Simple View Application**, so the creation of a Xcode Project of it.

This will have to be a blank App. The base of a simple app, the first in the wizard of Xcode.

Googling and searching on Stackoverflow, seems that the best option to my goal is the use of **Cmake**. Unfortunatelly the documentation of this tool, imho, is so poor.

The best answer that i've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822404/how-to-set-up-cmake-to-build-an-app-for-the-iphone). But the result, with some differences, is not working.
Another source that i've used is [this](https://github.com/sheldonth/ios-cmake).

My `CMakeLists.txt` is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)

project(tempProject)
set(NAME tempProject)
set(DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.1)
set(CODESIGNIDENTITY "iPhone Developer: XXX")
set(DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID "team id")

set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT iphoneos10.3)
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES $(ARCHS_STANDARD))
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-x objective-c++")

set(APP_TYPE MACOSX_BUNDLE)
set(PRODUCT_NAME ${NAME})
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME ${NAME})
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_NAME ${NAME})
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_STRING "bundle")
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER "bundle")
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME "bundle")
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_ICON_FILE "")
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_LONG_VERSION_STRING "1.0")
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING "1.0")
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION "1.0")
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_COPYRIGHT "Copyright YOU")
set(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET ${DEPLOYMENT_TARGET})

set(APP_HEADER_FILES
./AppDelegate.h
./ViewController.h
)

set(APP_SOURCE_FILES
./AppDelegate.m
./ViewController.m
)

set(RESOURCES
./Main.storyboard
./LaunchScreen.storyboard
)

add_executable(
${NAME}
${APP_TYPE}
${APP_HEADER_FILES}
${APP_SOURCE_FILES}
${RESOURCES}
)

find_library(UIKIT UIKit)
find_library(FOUNDATION Foundation)
find_library(MOBILECORESERVICES MobileCoreServices)
find_library(CFNETWORK CFNetwork)
find_library(SYSTEMCONFIGURATION SystemConfiguration)

set_target_properties(${NAME} PROPERTIES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "dwarf-with-dsym"
    RESOURCE "${RESOURCES}"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER "YES"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET ${DEPLOYMENT_TARGET}
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY ${CODESIGNIDENTITY}
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM ${DEVELOPMENT_TEAM_ID}
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY "1"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC YES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES "NO")
```

The major problems for me are:

- the structure of the dirs is different from an Xcode project generated via wizard;
- the automated signing of the project is disabled;
- if i try to run the App i've the following error:
  `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

P.S. If you know another way to my goal, you're welcome.