# Compiling for iOS with CMake

Tags: c++, ios, compilation, cmake, arm

I've compiled a C++ static library by using CMake as my building tool and I want to link it to my iOS app.
I created a simple 'Empty' application in Xcode and linked my library called libengine.a to it.
I tried to compile my iOS project and the linker gave me this warning:

```
ignoring file /Users/.../build/engine/libengine.a, 
file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386):
/Users/.../build/engine/libengine.a
```

As I understand it, I need to compile my library for ARM processors. The problem is I don't know how.
I think CMake really lacks good tutorials.
Anyways, my CMake scripts are attached below.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Tal.
Here is my main CMake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(movie-night)

if (DEFINED PLATFORM)
    include(toolchains/ios.cmake)
endif()

add_definitions(-Wall)

set(DEBUG)

if (DEFINED DEBUG)
    add_definitions(-g)
endif()

if (DEFINED RELEASE)
    add_definitions(-O3)
endif()

add_subdirectory(engine)
add_subdirectory(ui)

add_subdirectory(test)
```

Here is my toolchains/ios.cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Darwin)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use this toolchain file: http://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/ and use it as

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path_to_your_toolchain_file
```

Then, in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -arch armv7")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -arch armv7")
```

Comment: not works on cmake 2.8.11 errors: CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/Users/leanidchaika/job/lge/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/Users/leanidchaika/job/lge/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake

Comment: Here's a bit more recent fork of the linked toolchain: https://github.com/cristeab/ios-cmake

I ran into a couple of bugs with the old version that have been fixed in this one

Comment: Found [even newer fork](https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake) with `1K+` stars on GitHub!!

Answer (score 15):

By following [cmake-toolchains](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos) documentation I did like below:

```sh
cmake -G Xcode -B build \
    -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS \
    -DCMAKE_Swift_COMPILER_FORCED=true \
    -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0
```

*Note:* That assignment `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0` is not a mistake when targeting iOS.

Comment: I am using coturn master for Turn client library. I have successfully generated cmake build but the file libturnutils.a is mac os compatible. What changes should I make to make it cmpatible for ios?

Answer (score 3):

I've been using an updated version of the iOS CMake toolchain for quite a while: https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake

This creates an Xcode project which you can drag into an existing iOS project if necessary.

I wrote a blog post with more details: https://blog.tomtasche.at/2019/05/how-to-include-cmake-project-in-xcode.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a second version of iOS.cmake located at:

https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com

Note:  You may find that both versions of iOS.cmake will only build x86 versions of your project.  CMake now sets CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to the (latest) Mac OS X SDK available on your system.  You can fix this by modifying your copy of iOS.cmake to always set CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT.  You can do this by commenting out a couple of lines your copy of iOS.cmake:

```
# -- Under CMake 3.4.2, CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT is automatically defined to point to the latest Mac OS X SDK. --
# -- So, the iOS SDK is never found.  Grab the correct CMAKE_OS_SYSROOT and ignore any prior setting.   --

# If user did not specify the SDK root to use, then query xcodebuild for it.
# if (NOT CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT)
  execute_process(COMMAND xcodebuild -version -sdk ${XCODE_IOS_PLATFORM} Path
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT
    ERROR_QUIET
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  message (STATUS "Using SDK: ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT} for platform: ${IOS_PLATFORM}")
  message (STATUS "be sure the previous line points to the correct SDK")
# endif ( )
```