# Call Swift function from Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an old Objective-C project and I want to call new Swift function and object, I have create the file "`<ProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h`" and "`<ProjectName>-Swift.h`"

was easy for me call the function from Swift to Objective-C but I have a problem for reverse.

So I have create a simple class "System.Swift"

```
import Foundation

@objc class System : NSObject {

    @objc func printSome() {
        println("Print line System");
    }
    
}
```

now I have try to follow the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_84) and inside the `<...>-Swift.h` file I have write this

```
@class System;

@interface System : NSObject

-(void)printSome;

@end
```

and I have import it inside my Objective-C Class. At this point inside my Objective C class (currently UIViewController) of my Objective-C code I have try to call "printSome" method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    System * sis = [[System alloc] init];
    [sis printSome];
    //any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

now I have the following Error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "*OBJC_CLASS*$_System",
> referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in "ObjectiveC_Class_That_Call_Swift_Object".o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
> command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You have a linker error. Is it: (1) Xcode uses your product module name—not your target name—when naming the Objective-C bridging header and the generated header for your Swift code, or (2) make sure to import the Objective-C headers for those types prior to importing the Swift generated header into the Objective-C .m file you want to access the Swift code from? Do you have: #import “ProductModuleName-Swift.h” in your Objective-C code?

Comment: Yes i have read the documentation and the name of "ProductModelName" is currect... There is a bug that inside the Build Setting the Product model was not set... i have even set it...

Comment: @petert can you explain better the second point? I wrote everithing i did...

Comment: Problem Solved, i have add a new .h file in my project call <ProductModelName>-Swift.h but this is not necessary because the compiler just create this object even if i can't see it. I have delete the new file that i have create and now all run perfectly.  Tnx petert

Comment: You can answer your own questions - it might help others.

Comment: I know it's a really old question, but the title is misleading. You are trying to call a method, not a function.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Problem Solved, I previously create and included a new `.h` file in my **Objective-C** class named `<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h` but, as i discovered later, this step is not necessary because the compiler creates the necessary file invisible.

Simply include `<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h` in your class and it should work.

Comment: how about functions with parameters?

Comment: I am not able to access Swift functions with parameters and a return value, nor I am able to access Swift Functions without parameters and without a return value. I don't know why. My Swift Class is an NSObject, I imported the Foundation framework, the class and the functions have the `@objc` prefix. The `-Swift.h` has been automatically created. The thing that is making me headache is that I can call the Class itself but not any function inside it. Does anyone know why?

Comment: good example at http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/21/swift-calling-swift-functions-from-objective-c/

Comment: It is `<productModuleName>-.Swift.h` (not `model`).

Comment: If your Product name has any spaces in it, replace them with underscores, like: `#import "My_Project-Swift.h"`.

Comment: Note if the header name isn't obvious, you can look in your project build settings for 'Objective-C Generated Interface header name'

Answer (score 67):

It is strange but will work after we do:

1. Add `@objc` to your Swift-class ("`MySwiftClass`").
2. Add in Obj-C, i.e. the `.m` file:

   ```
   #import "(ProjectName)-Swift.h"
   ```
3. Declare in header .h

   ```
   @class MySwiftClass;
   ```

Compiler will generate the interface for `@objc` marked class in `MyModuleName-Swift.h` file.

Auto-Generated Obj-C Example:

```m
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC10Project17220PLHelper")
@interface PLHelper

+ (void)notifyForDownloading:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Comment: You can also override the Obj-C name of your Swift class using `@objc (MyClassName)`

Comment: For anyone who may do same dumb mistake as me. In step 2, make sure you use `(ProjectName)-Swift.h`, **NOT** `(ClassName)-Swift.h` !

Comment: thanks @Svitlana, unbelievable, it worked!!! But I have to retry many times these steps, including moving my added methods to other places in the class.

Comment: `3) @class SwiftClassName;` saved me

Comment: if your target name has any `spaces` add "_" (underscores instead of spaces) when creating swift.h import eg: if your target name is `Sample App` then your import statement would be `#import "Sample_App-Swift.h"`

Comment: I hope it helped lots of people, but this is the most inconsistent but accepted answer I have every seen

Answer (score 36):

Assume We have ProjectName "MyFirstProjectOnSwift" and swift class name "mySwiftClass" and objectiveC class is "MyObjectiveCLass"

Following steps are:-

> 1. Add #import "MyFirstProjectOnSwift-Swift.h" in "MyObjectiveCLass.m"
> 2. Add @class mySwiftClass in MyObjectiveCLass.h;
> 3. Then in MyObjectiveCLass.m
>
>    mySwiftClass *myClass = [mySwiftClass new];  {Call Like This in any
>      method wherever you want to call swift method.}
> 4. [myClass methodName];

Comment: mySwiftClass *myClass = [mySwiftClass new] its not working for me>>>>>

Comment: @HariNarayanan It should not be, do one think clear derived data and reopen your project.

Answer (score 13):

Check the -Swift.h file which has the import on your .m file in objective-C:

```
#import <YourProjectName-Swift.h>
```

Click on that line, and left-click - Jump To Definition.

This file should be included automatically, not manually.

Comment: My project name had a space in it; which looks like xcode replaced with an underscore for this file name.  But if you type the < left angle bracket after the #import statement, and start typing your project name - you'll likely see the correct .h file listed in xcode's code completion popup.

Answer (score 7):

Little additional tip for anyone stumbling upon this post and for hwhom the other answers do not work: you might also have to declare your Swift class "public".

Example:

`@objc public class MySwiftClass: NSObject {`

Answer (score 2):

If you're still not seeing your class even after importing `<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h`.

Make sure that your class is subclassing a native class (e.g `UIViewController`) or at least if it's just a utility class, make it subclass `NSObject`. Your class should now show.

Answer (score 0):

The recomended way for executing Swift code from Objective-C on projects that are being migrated from Obj-C to Swift is using Bridge/Proxy pattern.

1. Implement the Bridge.

`import Foundation`

`@objc class AnalyticsPropertyBridge: NSObject {`

```
private var analytics: AnalyticsManager = AnalyticsManager()

@objc func refreshProperties() {

    self.analytics.set(AnalyticsProperty.clientType)
}
```

`}`

2. Include the objC caller module in the umbrella file (Bridging-Header):

`#import "CallerModule.h"`

3. Finally in the caller .m file, two issues:

3.a Import umbrella file:

`#import "MyProject-Swift.h"`

3.b  Call the bridge.

`[[AnalyticsPropertyBridge new] refreshProperties];`

Benefits: Your swift code will not get dirty with @objc because code is being called from Objc. As time goes by, the ObjC will be reduced in your project and finally the bride will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

A note about project name, if there are spaces in project name make sure you replace them with underscore, for example if project name is "My Project" you need to include:

```
#import <My_Project-Swift.h>
```

Answer (score -3):

A good article out here if someone still having issues.

[Setting up Swift and Objective-C Interoperability](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-and-objective-c-interoperability-2add8e6d6887)

1. This article discusses in-depth how to import Swift files into ObjC as well as Objc files to Swift.
2. It also addresses a problem generally faced when the Project name has space in it.
3. It also discusses about “Product Module Name” flag.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.