# How to use Swift struct in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, constants

Simply I have a struct that stores the application constants as below:

```
struct Constant {

    static let ParseApplicationId = "xxx"
    static let ParseClientKey = "xxx"

    static var AppGreenColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(hexString: "67B632")
    }
}
```

These constants can be use in Swift code by calling `Constant.ParseClientKey` for example. But in my code, it also contains some Objective-C classes. So my question is how to use these constants in the Objective-C code?

If this way to declare constants is not good then what is the best way to create global constants to be used in both Swift and Objective-C code?

Comment: Please follow common swift code style and use a lowercase letter to start your let/var identifiers.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Would this not be the correct style for static properties of a struct? Much like `UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside`?

Comment: @LukeRogers `.TouchUpInside ` is an enumeration member, not a property of a struct.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Take a look at the Swift declaration: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlEvents — it's definitely a struct.

Comment: @LukeRogers That's because of Swift 2.0's changed way of how to import `NS_OPTIONS` style enums. Semantically `UIControlEvent` is still an enumeration type.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe LukeRogers: Dinh didn't ask about that issue, and most of us viewers didn't click here to read about it.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Sad to say, you can not expose `struct`, nor global variables to Objective-C. see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes), which states in part:

> Use Classes When You Need Objective-C Interoperability
>
> If you use an Objective-C API that needs to process your data, or you need to fit your data model into an existing class hierarchy defined in an Objective-C framework, you might need to use classes and class inheritance to model your data. For example, many Objective-C frameworks expose classes that you are expected to subclass.

As of now, IMHO, the best way is something like this:

```
let ParseApplicationId = "xxx"
let ParseClientKey = "xxx"
let AppGreenColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.7, blue: 0.3 alpha: 1.0)

@objc class Constant: NSObject {
    private init() {}

    class func parseApplicationId() -> String { return ParseApplicationId }
    class func parseClientKey() -> String { return ParseClientKey }
    class func appGreenColor() -> UIColor { return AppGreenColor }
}
```

In Objective-C, you can use them like this:

```
NSString *appklicationId = [Constant parseApplicationId];
NSString *clientKey = [Constant parseClientKey];
UIColor *greenColor = [Constant appGreenColor];
```

Comment: Accessible to Swift also?

Comment: @khunshan Yes. Accessible directly `ParseClientKey`, or via the class `Constant.clientKey()`

Comment: Should use ```@objc class Constant: NSObject```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

You will have to inherit from NSObject if you want to use "@objc"

i.e. @objc class Constant: NSObject { ... }

Comment: unfortunately, using @objc class Constant: NSObject { ... } will render `private init()` useless in Objective-C, since you can't limit the scope of inherited functions.

Comment: It could not find out `Constant` class. So i need must add `#import "(ProjectName)-Swift.h"` into `.m` file. See more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078043/call-swift-function-from-objective-c-class

Comment: This works but in Swift 4,  I also needed to put `@objc` in front of every `class func` to be able to call them from Objective C code.

Comment: @ElectroBuddha You can do ```@objcMembers``` on the class to reveal the whole class to Objective-C code.

Answer (score 28):

Why not create a file with both a `struct` and an `@objc class`, something like this:

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: Int) {
        let components = (
            R: CGFloat((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            G: CGFloat((hex >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            B: CGFloat((hex >> 00) & 0xff) / 255
        )
        self.init(red: components.R, green: components.G, blue: components.B, alpha: 1)
    }
}

extension CGColor {
    class func colorWithHex(hex: Int) -> CGColorRef {
        return UIColor(hex: hex).CGColor
    }
}

struct Constant {
    static let kParseApplicationId = "5678"
    static let kParseClientKey = "1234"
    static var kAppGreenColor: UIColor { return UIColor(hex:0x67B632) }
    static var kTextBlackColor: UIColor { return UIColor(hex:0x000000) }
    static var kSomeBgBlueColor: UIColor { return UIColor(hex:0x0000FF) }
    static var kLineGrayCGColor: CGColor { return CGColor.colorWithHex(0xCCCCCC) }
    static var kLineRedCGColor: CGColor { return CGColor.colorWithHex(0xFF0000) }
}


@objc class Constants: NSObject {
    private override init() {}

    class func parseApplicationId() -> String { return Constant.kParseApplicationId }
    class func parseClientKey() -> String { return Constant.kParseClientKey }
    class func appGreenColor() -> UIColor { return Constant.kAppGreenColor }
    class func textBlackColor() -> UIColor { return Constant.kTextBlackColor }
    class func someBgBlueColor() -> UIColor { return Constant.kSomeBgBlueColor }
    class func lineGrayCGColor() -> CGColor { return Constant.kLineGrayCGColor }
    class func lineRedCGColor() -> CGColor { return Constant.kLineRedCGColor }
}
```

For use in Objective-C files add this when you need to use constants:

```
#import "ProjectModuleName-Swift.h"
```

Swift usage:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = Constant.kAppGreenColor
```

Objective-C usage:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [Constants appGreenColor];
```

This way you can update colors, default text, web service urls for whole app in one place.

Comment: It wasn't immediately clear to me that we could scroll your answer to discover the objective-c part!

Answer (score 3):

Though this might be late or redundant, I could make it work with the following code :

```
@objcMembers class Flags: NSObject {
    static let abcEnabled = false
    static let pqrEnabled = false
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Obviously, to use in objc c code, you have to do #import "ProjectModuleName-Swift.h"

Answer (score 1):

You should make the let statements private if you want to make other Swift types in your code to access these constants only via class:

```
private let AppGreenColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.7, blue: 0.3 alpha: 1.0)

@objc class Constant {
    class func appGreenColor() -> UIColor { return AppGreenColor }
}
```

In Swift, you can use them like this:

```
UIColor *greenColor = Constant.appGreenColor
```

The following line will not compile anymore now since the let statement is private:

```
UIColor *greenColor = appGreenColor
```