# Cocoa Touch Framework: Constants

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

i want to write a Cocoa Touch Framework in Swift and want to use it in different projects. As far as everything works fine.

Now I would like to extend my framework with constants which I can use outside of the framework. My problem is that i can't use the constant from the Swift-Framework in my Objective-C project.

For example:
MyFramework.swift

```
 public struct Constants{
     public static let constant = "myConstant"
 }
```

and

```
public class MyClass : NSObject {

    public func myFunc(){
     doSomeThing
    }
}
```

In a Swift-Project i can access everything (MyClass and Constants). So this i what i want to do in Swift and Objective-C:

```
import MyFramework

class ClassWithImport{
 var xC = Constant.constant
}
```

But how can i make this in Objective-C?? At the moment i've in my MyFramework.h:

```
#import "MyFramework-Swift.h"
```

and this in the Class where I want to use the constants for example. After the import you can see i get access to MyClass, but i can't access the struct Constans.

```
#import <MyFramework.framework/Headers/MyFramework.h>

@implementation ClassWitheImport

- (void)funcOC
{
  MyClass *test;
  test.myFunc;
}
@end
```

Do I have to do that with the constants in a different way? The idea to make it this way, I came after I saw this link: [Global constants file in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252233/global-constants-file-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is the use of the struct. The struct is a swift only feature and isn't compatible to Objective-C.

A workaround can be found in the [post of rintaro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173234/how-to-use-swift-struct-in-objective-c).

Next to the link to his post I would like you also, just as he, provide the direct link to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_86) concerning the subject.