# Cannot call swift function in Objective C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I follow [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078043/call-swift-function-from-objective-c-class) on stack overflow and many other tutorials but still getting error while importing ProjectName-Swift.h file (Error: **file not found**). Into the Swift class I also added `@objc`:  **@objc class MySwiftClass**. Please help me know why I am getting the error **file not found** while importing ProjectName-Swift.h into the objective c file.

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods?

Comment: Yep, I have using cocoaPods into my project.

Comment: Is your project Objective-C and the swift class in cocoapods?

Comment: I marked my question as duplicate. So with another one who facing the same problem like me, please view the same question above to find the answer.