# How to access swift class in objective-c file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift2

I have a swift project and i import a singleton, objective-c coded class in the project.

I tried to import the productname_swift.h file but no luck.

How can i access swift class in that singleton class?

Comment: Refere this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102104/how-to-import-swift-code-to-objective-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: Answer updated to use swift class in Objective C.

Answer (score 5):

**Project made in Swift : To use Swift class in Objective C**

To use **Swift class in Objective C** , follow given steps :

1. Create one Objective C class named **User**.
2. A popup display with  "Would You like to configure an Objective-C bridging Header". Choose **Create Bridging Header**.

[image]

**User.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface User : NSObject

+(id) sharedUser ;

@end
```

**User.m**

```
#import "User.h"
#import "SwiftInObjectiveC-swift.h"


@implementation User


//Singleton of User

+(id)sharedUser{

    static User *sharedUser = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        sharedUser = [[self alloc] init];

        //Class Method of ViewController.swift
        [ViewController mySwiftClassFunction];


        //Instance Method of ViewController.swift
        ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [vc mySwiftFunction];

    });
    return sharedUser;
}

-(void) myObjcectivecMethod {

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [vc mySwiftFunction];

}
```

3. Add `@objc` in your .swift class in front of Class name.

   ```
    import UIKit

    @objc class ViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func mySwiftFunction() {

       print("Swift Function")
   }

   class func mySwiftClassFunction (){

       print("Swift Class Function")

   }

   }
   ```
4. Go to Build Settings.
5. Set **Product Module Name** : ProjectName

[image]

6. Set **Defines Module** : YES

[image]

7. Set **Embedded Content Contains Swift** : YES

[image]

8. Set **Install Objective-C Compatibility Header** : YES

[image]

9. Set **Objective-C Bridging Header** : SwiftInObjectiveC/SwiftInObjectiveC-Bridging-Header.h

[image]

10. Import Auto generated header "**ProjectName-swift.h**" in your ***.m** file.
11. Clean and Run your Project.
12. It will work!!!

Follow Apple link for [Mix and Match](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122) for detailed information.

[image]

Comment: The question is about using an Objective-C class in a project being made solely with Swift.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin :Thanks for alert me. I updated my answer to user Swift file in Objective C when project developed in Swift.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**It is very simple use Swift classes in Objective-C. Just follow steps given below**

- Open your Objective-C project.
- Add a new swift file to the project.
- One default dialogue will open to create a bridging header (If it
  does not open by default, add a bridging header file).
- Go to build settings type Swift Compiler and you will see Your
  `ProjectName-Swift.h` in Swift Compiler- General like below
  [image]
- Import you desired swift classes build and run.

Comment: thanks buddy your answer's helped me to fix my issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Adding multiple Swift files to an Objective-C project.**

Let’s say you want to add *Class1.swift*, *Class2.swift*, and *Class3.swift* file to the *SwiftToObjC* project

1. Add *Class1.swift* file to the project.
2. XCode will ask "Would You like to configure an Objective-C bridging Header"? You choose "Create Bridging Header". So the *SwiftToObjC-Bridging-Header.h* file as well as the *SwiftToObjC-Swift.h* file are generated.
3. In the SwiftToObjC-Bridging-Header.h file you add this line

> @class Class1;

4. When you add *Class2.swift* and *Class3.swift* to the project, you also add these two classes to the *SwiftToObjC-Bridging-Header.h* file as follows.

> @class Class1;
>
> @class Class2;
>
> @class Class3;

5. In the target SwiftToObjC, under *Build Settings*, *Swift-Compiler General* you should see these two settings:

> Objective-C Bridging Header -> SwiftToObjC-Bridging-Header.h
>
> Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name -> SwiftToObjC-Swift.h

6. In the target SwiftToObjC, under *Build Settings*, *Define Module* is set to YES.

7. If you want to access Class1 in say *MyViewController*, then in *MyViewController.m*, you should import.

> #import "SwiftToObjC-Bridging-Header.h"

8. In your *Class1.swift* file, declare your class as “@objc public” as follows. The same @objc public is used for Class2 and Class3.

> @objc public class Class1: UITableViewController

Note that: UITableViewController is only an example for demonstration purpose.

That’s all.

Comment: The way I understand it is that the key is the "-Swift.h" file. The compiler creates this file, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24087280/3017386
And, as mentioned in one of the comments, here: http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/21/swift-calling-swift-functions-from-objective-c/


The "-Bridging-Header.h" file contains headers which are supposed to be exposed _towards_ Swift, not the other way around.