# How to call swift class function from objective c class

Tags: objective-c, swift

The below code is written in swift class

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    dim(.In, alpha: dimLevel, speed: dimSpeed)
}


@IBAction func unwindFromEditAboutUs(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    dim(.Out, speed:dimSpeed)

}
```

I want to call this class functions from my objective C class....
plz. suggest me how can I do this...

Answer (score 1):

Simply import swift class in objective C Project

```
#import"ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make bridge to do this kind of stuff. [Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078043/call-swift-function-from-objective-c-class) or [this link](http://ericasadun.com/2014/08/21/swift-calling-swift-functions-from-objective-c/) and this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html). Hope this will help you :)

Comment: You should *explain and show* how it works instead of just pasting links, which is never an ideal answer...

Comment: I create the bridge-Header and used <"projectName"-swift.h> in my objective C class, I already saw the above link while google but i get stuck with these function in which UIStoryboardSegue is involved...... Plz explain with some example @Lion