# Calling Swift-Class initWith.. in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

My Swift-Class defines an initWith.. method by the following code

```
convenience init(controlType: ApplePencilControlType) {

    self.init(frame: CGRect())

    type = controlType

    self.frame = self.controlFrame

    if type == .zoom {

        zoomSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 20))

        if let slider = zoomSlider {

            self.addSubview(slider)
        }
    }
    else if type == .toLeft || type == .toRight {

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 20, height: 20))

        if let imgView = imageView {

            if let img = type.image {

                imgView.image = img
            }

            self.addSubview(imgView)
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to call this method by the following Objective-C Code makes Xcode show up an error.

```
- (void)presentOrHidePencilControls {

    self.apToLeft = [[ApplePencilControl alloc] initWithControlType:ApplePencilControlTypeToLeft];
}
```

The error is `No visible @interface for 'ApplePencilControl' declares the selector 'initWithControlType:'`

What have I to do, so i can call this initializer from Objective-C? The "Project/Modul-Swift.h" is already imported.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078043/call-swift-function-from-objective-c-class

Comment: @Lawliet will try to add the '@objc' After lunch :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had to insert `@objc` and `: Int` to my enum definition in the same class.