# Passing data from Objective-C Viewcontroller to Swift ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to pass data from an objective-c ViewController to a Swift ViewController and I'm getting this error in my Objective-C controller:

> Property 'type' not found on object of type 'UIViewController'

My Objective-C code:

```
UIViewController *mainController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdentitySelfieViewController"];
mainController.type = "passport";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainController animated:YES];
```

Import into the Bridging-header file:

```
#import "PassportViewController.h"
```

And created the corresponding String into my Swift View Controller

```
let type = ""
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: You need to create an object out of the Objective-C imported class.

Comment: Oh... may I kindly ask if you have any example to share with me? Thank you

Comment: I haven't done it for a year, but I think it's somethink like the following.  let passportInstance: PassportViewController = PassportViewController()

Comment: I will investigate this, thank you :)

Comment: Create Object of Swift class. e.g `IdentitySelfieViewController  * mainController`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Solution to your problem is like that :

First in your Swift Controller add the `@Objc` before the class keyword like that :

```
@objc class ViewController: UIViewController
```

and that in that controller create a variable like that :

```
public var myValue:String  = ""
```

After this in your `Objective-C` ViewController you need to import this and keep in mind this is very important.

```
#import "TargetName-Swift.h"
```

TargetName should be replaced by your target name. After this you can easily call the variables of that Swift Controller like that:

```
ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];
vc.myValue = @"Hello";
```

Comment: You are my hero :) Thank you so much for your time and for your answer.

Comment: So my variable is recognized; it seems I can pass it from Objective-C to Swift. How would you retrieve the value in your Swift Controller? Rather than putting this: public var myValue:String  = "" - Thanks again

Comment: its very simple after passing the value you can just the variable in the Swift Controller , it will have that values that you passed.

Comment: or anyone who may do same dumb mistake as me. In step 2, make sure you use (ProjectName)-Swift.h, NOT (ClassName)-Swift.h from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078043/call-swift-function-from-objective-c-class

Comment: In my case Swift4.2, I need to add @objc before the variable declaration.
Example: `@objc public var myValue:String  = ""`

Comment: @MoosaBaloch That did the trick for me too, so that's important to remember.

Comment: @objc var foo = "" is not working in swift 5 or xcode 11.2.1

Answer (score 7):

This is your swift class

**Step 1:**

```
class SwiftClassController: UIViewController {
//Required variables
@objc var deviceId: String?
@objc var deviceObj: CustomType?
```

**Step 2:**

In Objective C class import `#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"`

**Step 3:**

In your Objective C class access variable from Swift file

```
YourViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourVC"];
vc.deviceId = @"1234567";
vc. deviceObj = yourCustomObject;
```