# Is there any way I can use SwiftyJSON in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am using both Swift and Objective-C in my code. I have already used Objective-C libraries in Swift and few Swift libraries in Objective-C classes. I need to use SwiftyJSON in Objective-C. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html (see "Importing Swift into Objective-C")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Swift function from Objective C class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078043/call-swift-function-from-objective-c-class)

Comment: You can't. SwiftyJSON is designed for Swift. Use https://github.com/bernikowich/NSTEasyJSON instead.

Comment: @matt I have checked NSTEasyJSON.

Answer (score 4):

You can consume Swift frameworks/libraries from Objective-C if they are designed to conform to the interfaces that Objective-C understands. Swift has lots of constructs that don't have an equivalent in Objective-C, so a library that is not written to support Objective-C won't work.

As Matt says, SwiftyJSON is a Swift-only library.

Duncan

Comment: Yes you are right. Because I have used a bunch of swift libraries for Objective C. But SwiftyJSON is only meant for Swift