# How do i call swift function from objective c file in same project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3, bridge

I created one swift project on `Xcode 9` using `Swift 4`. And and some objective c .h and .m files in my swift project by creating.h bridge file.

I am able to call objective c function from swift class but now i want to call swift function from objective c .h and .m file.

But i am not able to call swift function from objective c function

So what are the steps about that?

Comment: thank you everyone to gave answer my question. I got answer of this question as more clearly. please refers bellow given link    http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/

Answer (score 1):

Importing `"<ProductName>-Swift.h"` at the top of your objc file should work.

For example:

`#import myCuteCat-Swift.h`

Also, don't forget `@objc` to the Swift method/attribute you want to expose.

Comment: Please can you explian me as details stepwise? Means which productfile? Can you give me example?

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a Swift function or property from Objective-C you have to mark it with the `@objc` keyword. Example:

`@objc func myFunc()`

Comment: Where do i define @objc func in my project?

Comment: It’s a keyword. You don’t need to define it. Prepend the function or property with it as I did in my example above.

Comment: means directly use my swift function into objective c class. is their no need to import anything in objective c? and how do compiler know if I have same name swift function in my project which function want to call?

Comment: Nope. No imports needed. That’s what the bridging header is for. It does that for you.

Comment: Why don’t you go try it and see. Try first, ask second.

Comment: Yes I tried I mark @objc func myFunction name in my swift file and now I call it from my objective c file but it does not seem in my objective c file and does not jump to definition so asked you for details. Is I t write way or not? Now when I call from objective c its get me error "Implicit declaration of function 'my function' is invalid in C99"

Comment: Well, it appears now that this question has been marked as a duplicate, so I'll bet that following the directions here will work great: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078043/call-swift-function-from-objective-c-class