# Integrating Box2d in Swift project gets cassert file not found error

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, swift, box2d

I want to integrate Box2d in my OS X application, so I've used the following Podfile to grab it:

```
pod 'box2d'
```

And the version of box2d is 2.3.0. In the xcworkspace I got from `pod install`, I've created a bridge header to interoperate with the C++ APIs (according to doc, developer cannot import C++ projects directly from Swift lang, you should create a ObjC bridge).

And when I hit build button, I got a compiler error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: /path/to/project/Pods/Headers/Box2D/Common/b2Settings.h:22: 'cassert' file not found
```

So I wonder how can I fix this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out by myself.

I've already created the bridging file as mentioned in apple's doc, but the content I was putting there was:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//
#import <Box2d/Box2d.h>
```

This is the root for the compiler error. So, I have to create a new Objective-C class, rename the `.m` file to `.mm`, and put the line of import in the `.mm` file. **NOTE:** putting the import line in `.h` file does not solve the compiler error.

And that's it, now it compiles happily.

Comment: Once you resolved this issue, how are you able to use Box2D in your Swift code?  Can you provide a code sample?