# Building C++ and Assembly source in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, assembly

I'm trying to build a command-line application in Xcode for OS X 10.9 which contains a .cpp source file, which uses a function externally defined in a .asm assembly file. The C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void NOTHING();

int main(){

    NOTHING();

    return 0;    
}
```

The following is the assembly function:

```
global NOTHING

section .text

NOTHING:

    mov eax, 0
    ret
```

It's a program that does nothing but temporarily move the value zero into the EAX register. I made sure to choose NASM assembly when creating the .asm source file. When I hit the 'play' button to build the executable, Xcode simply states **build failed**, without specifying a reason.

---

I could revert back to doing it all in the command line, as I would on Linux. However, if possible, I'd prefer to start using Xcode, as it combines many tools, e.g. Git, into a single application for development.

---

**EDIT:** After the answer, I have decided to abandon Xcode; the command line is just much simpler. Based on the answer, I have written the following 'makefile' for future users visiting the question:

```
test: main.cpp asm.o
    g++ -stdlib=libstdc++ main.cpp asm.o -o test

asm.o: asm.asm
    nasm -f macho64 asm.asm -o asm.o
```

which assumes the assembly file is 'asm.asm', the C++ 'main.cpp', and the executable created is named 'test.' As in the answer, make sure functions in the .asm file begin with an underscore.

Comment: You can see the reason for each file in the organizer (on the left side of Xcode).

Comment: @user3477950: It appears there's a problem with the linker; says symbols not found for architecture x86_64.

Comment: @userXXX And which symbols aren't found? Perhaps you just need to link against the C++ standard library.

Comment: @user3477950: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NOTHING", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" I read that you had to use _NOTHING rather than NOTHING in the .asm code. I did that, but still got the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `-f macho64` - for 64 bit x86-64 Mach-O object files. As you've already seen, Mach-O (function) symbols are prefixed with an underscore. So if you give the function definition `NOTHING`, you must provide the global `_NOTHING` in the assembly.

Also, a function with `"C"` linkage should be specified as: `void NOTHING (void);`

Comment: +1 until the last sentence. We aren't in the K&R C days anymore, personal style preferences should be left out imho.

Comment: Abandoned Xcode, and did everything in the command line; your suggestions worked.

Comment: @JustSid - It is still better practice, since it's function with C linkage. Putting the same declaration in C source will silently accept any arguments.