# Call a C++ function from Swift

Tags: c++, c, xcode, swift, linker

How should I call a C++ function (no classes involved) from a Swift file?
I tried this:

In **someCFunction.c**:

```
void someCFunction() {
    printf("Inside the C function\n");
}

void aWrapper() {
    someCplusplusFunction();
}
```

In **someCpluplusfunction.cpp**:

```
void someCplusplusFunction() {
    printf("Inside the C++ function");
}
```

In **main.swift**:

```
someCFunction();
aWrapper();
```

In **Bridging-Header.h**:

```
#import "someCFunction.h"
#import "someCplusplusFunction.h"
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24042893/3503736) very informative, but still I cannot make it work.
Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What does the header look like?

If you want to explicitly set the linking type for C-compatible functions in C++, you need to tell the C++ compiler so:

```
// cHeader.h

extern "C" {
    void someCplusplusFunction();
    void someCFunction();
    void aWrapper();
}
```

Note that this isn't valid C code, so you'd need to wrap the `extern "C"` declarations in preprocessor macros.

On OS X and iOS, you can use `__BEGIN_DECLS` and `__END_DECLS` around code you want linked as C code when compiling C++ sources, and you don't need to worry about using other preprocessor trickery for it to be valid C code.

As such, it would look like:

```
// cHeader.h

__BEGIN_DECLS
void someCplusplusFunction();
void someCFunction();
void aWrapper();
__END_DECLS
```

EDIT: As ephemer mentioned, you can use the following preprocessor macros:

```
// cHeader.h

#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" { 
#endif 
void someCplusplusFunction();
void someCFunction();
void aWrapper();
#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly for this example. 
Xcode still doesn't want to link the real project, but I'll continue the investigations.

Comment: I found the problem with the real project: I am trying to pass a string as an argument to the C++ function. 
According to what I read, a Swift **String** should be casted automatically to a C **const char\***, but I suppose I am missing something...

Comment: If only I coded what I preach... In my code, I mixed up **const char\*** and **char\***.
To resume: @MaddTheSame gave the good answer. Nothing to add, but a thanks :-)

Comment: "You'd need to wrap the `extern "C"` declarations in preprocessor macros", specifically: `#ifdef __cplusplus  extern "C" {  #endif ` your C function definitions here... `#ifdef __cplusplus  }  #endif`. I can't put line breaks in a comment, but you'd need line breaks before and after the "extern C {" and the "}"

Comment: Thanks mate :) @MaddTheSane