# Swift: How to call a C function loaded from a dylib

Tags: c, swift, macos, dylib

Is there a way to call a C function loaded from a dylib from Swift?

This is my **dylib** file:

cppdemofile.cpp

```
#include "cppdemofile.h"

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

cppdemofile.h

```
#ifndef __CppDemoLibrary__cppdemofile__
#define __CppDemoLibrary__cppdemofile__

#pragma GCC visibility push(default)

extern "C" int add(int a, int b);

#pragma GCC visibility pop

#endif
```

compile to dylib and check:

```
nm -gU libCppDemoLibrary.dylib
0000000000000f80 T _add
```

... copy `libCppDemoLibrary.dylib` to `~/lib`...

**Swift program**:

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(sender: NSButton) {
    let handle = dlopen("libCppDemoLibrary.dylib", RTLD_NOW)
    if (handle != nil) {
        var sym = dlsym(handle, "add")
        if (sym != nil) {
            let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<(CInt, CInt) -> CInt>(sym)

            // When debugging, I'm reaching up to this point...
            // but now, how do I call the 'add' function here???
            // var result = ???

            // label.stringValue = "Total: " + String(result)
        }
    }
}
```

How do I call the `add` function? Is it ok to use a dylib? Should I instead add these sources to my swift project?

Comment: 1. Why dyld? 2. Have you tried making it into a module and importing it from Swift?

Comment: See http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/23/c-libraries-swift/

Comment: The question title is a bit misleading because `add` has C linkage. You couldn't call a C++ function from Swift.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Calling the `add` function from Swift is possible because you 
defined it to have C linkage with `extern "C"`.

Making the library a Swift module (as suggested by jtbandes in above
comments) might be the better solution, 
but here is how you can use the function pointer return by `dlsym()` from Swift:

First add

```
typedef int(*addFunc)(int, int);
```

to the bridging header file, or alternatively define

```
typealias addFunc = @convention(c) (CInt, CInt) -> CInt
```

in Swift. Then the following works:

```
let handle = dlopen(path, RTLD_NOW)
if (handle != nil) {
    var sym = dlsym(handle, "add")
    if (sym != nil) {
        let f = unsafeBitCast(sym, addFunc.self)
        let result = f(12, 45)
        print(result)
    }
    dlclose(handle)
}
```

Of course this will crash if `addFunc` does not match the
actual signature of the loaded function.

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
if let handle = dlopen(path, RTLD_NOW) {
    if let sym = dlsym(handle, "add") {
        let f = unsafeBitCast(sym, to: addFunc.self)
        let result = f(12, 45)
        print(result)
    }
    dlclose(handle)
}
```

Comment: This one worked great. Thanks also for the suggestion to make this a module.

Comment: @Andres: You are welcome! – The suggestion however came from  jtbandes in his comment to your question :)

Comment: Will iOS apps using this API be rejected for App Store?

Comment: @chrisamanse: Most  probably if you use it to call non-public APIs.  (*This* question was about macOS, not iOS.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use C++ code in Swift, you need to wrap it in C functions or Objective-C classes.

Also see [Call a C++ function from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805097/call-a-c-function-from-swift/26813226#26813226)