# Call C function from Swift knowing only memory address

Tags: c, swift, callback, language-interoperability

I have a very simple function in C and its pointer gets passed into Swift.

```
void callback() {
    NSLog(@"such pointer…");
}
```

How can it be invoke in Swift using **ONLY** the pointer? This is **NOT** about simply invoking it – it works fine when invoked directly. Tried the following and different variations with signature casting, but it always crashes:

```
let pointer: UnsafePointer<@convention(c)() -> ()> = UnsafePointer(bitPattern: …)
let callback: @convention(c)() -> () = pointer.memory
Swift.print(callback) // (Function)
callback() // Handling crash with signal 11...
```

Tried defining `Callback` type with `typedef void(*Callback)();` – same thing:

```
let pointer: UnsafePointer<Callback> = UnsafePointer(bitPattern: …)
let callback: Callback = pointer.memory
Swift.print(callback) // (Function)
callback() // Handling crash with signal 11...
```

To check that it actually works and points to the right address I have another Objective-C function, which works as expected when invoked from Swift with the callback pointer.

```
void invokeCallback(uintptr_t callback) {
    ((void (*)()) callback)(); // such pointer…
}
```

Comment: How do you obtain the pointer? What's its definition/declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same approach as in [Swift: How to call a C function loaded from a dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669958/swift-how-to-call-a-c-function-loaded-from-a-dylib) should work here.

Example for Swift 3 (assuming that `funcPtr` is a
`UnsafeRawPointer` containing the function's address):

```
// Define function type:
typealias callbackFunc = @convention(c) () -> Void

// Convert pointer to function type:
let callback = unsafeBitCast(funcPtr, to: callbackFunc.self)

// Call function:
callback()
```

Of course the type alias must match the actual function signature,
and the function needs to be a "pure" C function (not an Objective-C
method).

Comment: Hah i was trying all kinds of random shit trying to figure this out. `@convention(c)` is the ticket

Comment: Ha, I've seen a couple of your answers with `unsafeBitCast`, shame didn't try it first. This is a lifesaver. Thanks Martin!