# Where to put a custom .dylib in a Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to load a custom .dylib library via the `dlopen()` function (in a Swift iOS app). It requires a path to the library.

- Where to put the library in the project structure?
- What will be the library's path on the iOS device?

Also, a tangential question, it seems more usual to include the library's sources directly into the project and let Xcode build it. Is that a preferable approach for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 )

If you include the .dylib library in with your list of files and resources in your project, you can use the "`Copy Files`" build phase to copy the dylib into your shipping app.

A tutorial [can be seen here](https://jyhong.blog.ustc.edu.cn/2015/07/add-3rd-part-dynamic-library-dylib-to-xcode-target/).

2 )

For `dlopen`, try using just the `.dylib` name before you try to use relative paths including the "`@executable_path`" or "`@rpath`" run time variables.  An example can be seen [here in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669958/swift-how-to-call-a-c-function-loaded-from-a-dylib).

As for why some developers prefer to include the library source code in a project, I believe it's mostly just a preference by folks who aren't comfortable with the "Copy Files" build phase or in using `dlopen`.