# How to invoke swift function from lldb using address (pointer)?

Tags: objective-c, swift, debugging, lldb

I'm playing with `lldb` and I'm trying to call my swift static function. I was able to find its details in image, however I have no idea how to call it and pass arguments.

My output:

```
(lldb) image lookup -vs $S5project19ViewControllerUtilsC07setRootbC010storyboard13withAnimationySo12UIStoryboardC_SbtFZ
1 symbols match '$S5project19ViewControllerUtilsC07setRootbC010storyboard13withAnimationySo12UIStoryboardC_SbtFZ' in /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC7A5199-424E-4E38-A8A8-CB99C7D8CF82/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BE7BB249-DB64-4228-B64E-EB430BCCE29E/project.app/project:
        Address: project[0x00000002000fc970] (project.__TEXT.__text + 1027840)
        Summary: project`static project.ViewControllerUtils.setRootViewController(storyboard: __C.UIStoryboard, withAnimation: Swift.Bool) -> () at ViewControllerUtils.swift:7
         Module: file = "/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DC7A5199-424E-4E38-A8A8-CB99C7D8CF82/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BE7BB249-DB64-4228-B64E-EB430BCCE29E/project.app/project", arch = "x86_64"
    CompileUnit: id = {0x00000000}, file = "/Users/user/mobile/company/iOS/project/project/Utils/ViewControllerUtils.swift", language = "swift"
       Function: id = {0x7700000075}, name = "static project.ViewControllerUtils.setRootViewController(storyboard: __C.UIStoryboard, withAnimation: Swift.Bool) -> ()", mangled = "$S5project19ViewControllerUtilsC07setRootbC010storyboard13withAnimationySo12UIStoryboardC_SbtFZ", range = [0x000000010bd0c780-0x000000010bd0c82e)
       FuncType: id = {0x7700000075}, byte-size = 8, decl = ViewControllerUtils.swift:7, compiler_type = "(UIKit.UIStoryboard, Swift.Bool) -> ()
"
         Blocks: id = {0x7700000075}, range = [0x10bd0c780-0x10bd0c82e)
      LineEntry: [0x000000010bd0c780-0x000000010bd0c79d): /Users/user/mobile/company/iOS/project/project/Utils/ViewControllerUtils.swift:7
         Symbol: id = {0x00002a71}, range = [0x000000010ac0c780-0x000000010ac0c830), name="static project.ViewControllerUtils.setRootViewController(storyboard: __C.UIStoryboard, withAnimation: Swift.Bool) -> ()", mangled="$S5project19ViewControllerUtilsC07setRootbC010storyboard13withAnimationySo12UIStoryboardC_SbtFZ"
       Variable: id = {0x6600000092}, name = "storyboard", type = "UIKit.UIStoryboard", location =  DW_OP_fbreg(-16), decl = ViewControllerUtils.swift:7
       Variable: id = {0x66000000a0}, name = "withAnimation", type = "Swift.Bool", location =  DW_OP_fbreg(-24), decl = ViewControllerUtils.swift:7
       Variable: id = {0x66000000ae}, name = "self", type = "@thick project.ViewControllerUtils.Type", location =  DW_OP_fbreg(-32), decl = ViewControllerUtils.swift:7
```

Source code:

```
final class ViewControllerUtils {
    static func setRootViewController(storyboard: UIStoryboard, withAnimation: Bool) {
        setRootViewController(window: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow, storyboard: storyboard, withAnimation: withAnimation)
    }
}
```

I know I could switch to `Swift` and invoke something like this:

```
expression -l swift -O -- ViewControllerUtils.setRootViewController(storyboard: UIKit.UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil), withAnimation: true)
```

But I would like to learn how to invoke a function using **its address** or symbol without referencing to specific class like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution.

1. Take address from range: `Symbol: id = {0x00002a71}, range = [0x000000010ac0c780-0x000000010ac0c830)` this one: `0x000000010ac0c780`.
2. Import UIKit `(lldb) po import UIKit`
3. Create `Storyboard`:

> ```
> (lldb) p UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)  
> (UIStoryboard) $R2 = 0x00006000006c8200 {  
>   ObjectiveC.NSObject = {  
>     isa = UIStoryboard  
>   }  
> }
> ```

4. Cast raw address to function and invoke it using created `Storyboard` variable `$R2`:
   `(lldb) po unsafeBitCast(0x000000010ac0c780, to: (@convention(c)(UIKit.UIStoryboard, Bool) -> ()).self)($R2, true)`

Here you can read also an interesting example of importing C function: [Swift: How to call a C function loaded from a dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669958/swift-how-to-call-a-c-function-loaded-from-a-dylib)