# SVM or Quadratic Programming Solver for Objective-C or Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, svm

I'll admit up-front I'm probably in over my head. I'm trying to get through Caltech's "Learning From Data" online course and we're on Support Vector Machines. The course is language-agnostic, so I picked Swift since I wanted to learn it and already know a bit about objective-C. A couple of weeks ago for the Linear Regression section, I managed to find some help in using Accelerate for matrix math and making my own solver, but the professor was pretty specific this time that it won't be reasonable for us to make our own QP solver. Unfortunately, every package I seem to find is either for other languages, or a paid product.

Does anyone know how to solve QP optimization in objective-C or Swift? Can I get Accelerate to do it somehow, or is there a free framework I can use?

Answer (score 0):

There is the computer vision library [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) which contains implementations for SVMs and other tools for *learning from data*. OpenCV can also be used from Objective C though it is a C++ library.

Comment: Do you know if OpenCV can work with Swift? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: As far as i know, it's not possible to use C++ directly from Swift. You'll have to create an objective-c wrapper for the features, you're using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files