# Boost c++ library in Swift results to "vector not found"

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift

I'm tring to introduce Boost Clipping c++ library into Swift. I have the following files but the source code is too long to paste here in entirety:

clipper.cpp
clipper.h:

```
#ifndef clipper_h
#define clipper_h
#define CLIPPER_VERSION "6.2.0"
#include <vector>
#include <set>
...
```

MyProject-Bridging-Header.h:

```
#include "AnswerToEverything.h"
#include "clipper.h"
```

However this results into:

[image]

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files

Comment: Thanks, the related question covers similar topic but as a noobie, I would need the answer spelled out for me. I have the basic setup working but accessing c++ namespaces etc. seems quite complicated.