# Can I use C++ API's with swift?

Tags: swift

I want to use the crypto++ library in my iPhone app. Is this possible with the way OBJ-C/C++ are integrated with Swift? I have tried to add it as a library, but I am not sure how to call it.

Comment: You may need a C an Objective-C wrapper. It really depends on the interface exposed by the C++ library.

Comment: Just clarifying @uchuugaka comment. You **definitely** need an objective C wrapper since there is no way for Swift to interact directly with c++

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I mix Swift with C++? Like the Objective - C .mm files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files)