# Can I merge in iOS a Swift app with a C++ app (Vuforia)?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, swift, vuforia

I have developed an app in Swift for iOS and I would like to add an augmented reality feature using Vuforia for cloud recognition. Now I have two different apps, the main one in Swift and the AR app using Vuforia (C++). I would like to merge them and make the AR just an option in my main Swift app, that's it, in my main Swift app I would touch a button an open the AR scanning feature. How can this be done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your C++ library interface in an Objective-C++ interface which can then be accessed via swift.

See: [Can I mix Swift with C++? Like the Objective - C .mm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files)