# Bridging objective-c library in swift project does not work

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift

In my swift project in need to use snmp++ project ( https://github.com/Zchander/mobile-snmp-plusplus ). The snmp++ project is written in c++ and then objective-c wrapper is created for functions.

The project generates libMobileSNMP_PP.a file which i include in my swift project and then create a bridging header and in the bridging header inport "XISMobile_SNMP_PP.h".

Also included .mm and .h files in the swift project as shown in the attached image example1

[image]

at compile it gives "could not reference bridging file in the app".

I refered link [Can I mix Swift with C++? Like the Objective - C .mm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files) but still issue exist.

I even tried steps as given in example as shown https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch/tree/master/SwiftStitch but no success.

Please tell where i'm doing or missing any step.

Comment: Hey how did you solved this issue? i'm having a similar problem while connected this library with my swift project and i'm badly stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tell your Swift Compiler about your Objective-C Bridging Header?

[image: Swift Bridging Header]

If not, go to your project and click your target. Go to build settings and down tords the bottom you will see the Swift compiler as shown in the image. Add your header file there and recompile.

Comment: even after adding the bridging header file in Build settings... same issue exists.

Comment: It is allowing you to use the objc code in your .swift, it just wont compile and run?