# Include C++ header file in Swift

Tags: c++, swift, vector, include, bridging-header

I have a C++ header file (named `header.h`) which I want to include into my Swift project.

Since the C++ framework I want to include is not finished yet I just have the header file for now.

My C++ header file `header.h` looks a little like this:

```
#include <vector>

struct someStruct{
    float someAttr;
}

class someClass{
    public:
        enum SomeEnum{
            Option1,
            Option2
        }

        void someFunc(const double value) {}
}
```

Problem is, when I try to include the `header.h` file in the `project-Bridging-Header.h` it will never find vector which I include in header.h

[image: 'vector' file not found]

I tried renaming `header.h` to `header.hpp`.
I tried setting the bridging headers Type to C++ Header in the right panel.
But none of them helped.

I hope some of you can help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.swiftprogrammer.info/swift_call_cpp.html)?

Comment: I have tried adding a wrapper although this would lead to a loss in classes which I need to be able to use in Swift Code

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24202940/4700426 , hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately the problem with all these answer out there, is that they won't give me the opportunity to use classes I defined in C++. I will only be able to wrap methods so this will result in static functions which don't help too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use a C++ class in Swift directly, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-ID0:

> You cannot import C++ code directly into Swift. Instead, create an
>   Objective-C or C wrapper for C++ code.

Actually, a convenient way of wrapping C++ for use in Swift is Objective-C++.  Objective-C++ source files can contain both Objective-C and C++ code, mixed.  Here is a quick partial example based on the code snippet in your question.  Only `someClass` is partially wrapped here.  In production code you would also need to consider memory management.

The wrapper's header file, `mywrapper.h`, has no traces of C++:

```
#ifndef mywrapper_h
#define mywrapper_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// This is a wrapper Objective-C++ class around the C++ class
@interface someClass_oc : NSObject

-(void)someFunc:(double)value;

@end

#endif /* mywrapper_h */
```

Here is the Objective-C++ implementation, `mywrapper.mm`.  Please note the `.mm` extension.  You can create an Objective-C file with an `.m` and then rename it.

```
    #import "mywrapper.h"
    #import "header.h"  // CAN import a C++ header here, in Objective-C++ code

    // Use an extension on someClass_oc because we need to use someClass,
    // but we couldn't do it in mywrapper.h,
    // which is visible from Swift and thus can't contain C++ stuff.
    @interface someClass_oc ()
    {
        someClass * ptrSomeClass;
    }
    @end

    @implementation someClass_oc

    -(id)init
    {
        // In this example ptrSomeClass is leaked...
        ptrSomeClass = new someClass();
        return self;
    }

    -(void)someFunc:(double)value
    {
        ptrSomeClass->someFunc(value);
    }

    @end
```

Now you can import `mywrapper.h` in the bridging header and then do something like this in Swift:

```
let x = someClass_oc()

x.someFunc(123.456)
```

Thus you can create an object in Swift, which is backed by an instance of your C++ class.

This is just a quick example to give you an idea.  If your run into other problems, they would probably deserve separate questions.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I probably need to wrap the classes and its function completely or rewrite the framework in swift.