# How to call functions in c++ library from a cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a huge c++ library that i need to make use of. Due to the sheer size of the library its almost impossible to write a objective c wrapper for each and every function. Will making the objective c file with .mm extension solve the problem?

I have made the cocoa file with extension.mm and other files are in .cpp , i still get a linker error. Hence, i was wondering if this is sufficient or should i still make a wrapper!

Comment: Yeah it will work.

Comment: Yes tried, still getting  linker errors!

Comment: duplicate - check out the samples here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files (I'd stay away from xcode 8 until GM)

Comment: Works, my mistake was naming even the c++ files with extension .mm. Thanks!