# Use C++ library from Swift in iOS App

Tags: c++, ios, swift, ginac

I want to use a C++ library in Swift: [GiNaC](http://www.ginac.de). I have seen tutorials on how to use C++ libraries in Swift but I do not know if this will work for iOS or how to deal with dependencies. GiNaC has [CLN](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/) as a dependency. How to achieve this?

Comment: Generally speaking, when posting on stackoverflow, you should attempt to solve your problem and then post a question about where you're stuck.  "How do I do 'x'?" isn't a valid post.

Answer (score 2):

C++ .h files cannot be imported in a Swift Bridging Header because Swift is not compatible with C++ only with C or Objective-C

You will probably need to use an Objective-C wrapper you create to call the C++ functions,  then Swift can call the methods exposed by your Objective-C wrapper.

This thread is relevant : [Can I mix Swift with C++? Like the Objective-C .mm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files)