# Unknown type name 'wchar_t',bool. Error showing while a library of C++ importing in Xcode(Swift)

Tags: c++, ios, swift, xcode

I am integrating a printer library in swift. The library is in C++ language. I imported the C++ library to the project and create the bridge header file.This bridge code is given here

```
#import "printerlibs_caysnpos/printerlibs_caysnpos.h"

//const char *CaysnPos_LibraryVersion(void);
int CaysnPos_KickOutDrawer(void * handle, int nDrawerIndex, int nHighLevelTime, int nLowLevelTime);
```

After compiling the code, error is coming in library file.The error is "Unknown type name 'wchar_t'" and "Unknown type name 'bool'".There wchar_t and bool is the parameter of function, That is written here

```
 PRINTERLIBS_API void * CaysnPos_OpenBT4ByConnectW(const wchar_t *address);
 PRINTERLIBS_API void CaysnPos_SetBT4WriteMode(void * handle, bool bHighSpeed, unsigned int nPacketSize, unsigned int nPacketTimeout, unsigned int nPacketMaxRetry);
```

Can anyone help me to remove this error and  how to access the methods of C++ methods in swift file.

Comment: Can you review you sentence beginning with 'Firstly' because I don't undertand what you write !!! The 'and written' seems to be incorrect. For me, something is missing.

Comment: I changed, hope this will help you to understand

Comment: I think that your answer is already on StackOverflow [here]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790460/use-c-library-from-swift-in-ios-app)