# Compiling the Structure framework (Objective-C++ code?) in a Swift Project

Tags: swift, xcode, objective-c++

Having a devil of a time and Structure's docs aren't helping. Trying to compile their stuff in a Swift project. It gets hung up on a struct definition. Any ideas as to what might be wrong? Shot in the dark?

[image]

Comment: All header files included from the Swift bridging header file are compiled as C files. You cannot import C++ declarations into Swift.

Comment: Not even Objective-C++?

Comment: No (Objective-C++ is an extension of C++). Compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/24042774/1187415.