# How to include a C++ module from a Swift package, in another module or an Xcode project

Tags: c++, objective-c, module, swift-package-manager

**Summary:** Problems with C++ header imports when creating a Swift package containing a C++ module and an Obj-C module.

*There is no Swift code involved in the modules or the "clients" here - this is just about using Swift Package Manager to create and use the modules.  I have often used C++ code from Objective-C clients (and from Objective-C wrappers used by Swift code) in the past using frameworks.*

I am trying to use  the Swift Package Manager to create a package that contains both C++ and Objective-C APIs.  I have a Swift package, with working unit tests, structured as follows: `MyPackageCPP` is a C++ implementation; `MyPackage` is an objective-C wrapper around that.

The Package.swift file for this is

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyPackageCPP", targets: ["MyPackageCPP"]),
        .library(name: "MyPackage", targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackageCPP",
            path: "Sources/MyPackageCPP",
            publicHeadersPath: "include"
        ),
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: ["MyPackageCPP"],
            path: "Sources/MyPackage",
            exclude: [
                "Info.plist",
            ],
            publicHeadersPath: "include"
        ),
        .testTarget( // C++ tests
            name: "MyPackageCPPTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackageCPP"]
        ),
        .testTarget( // Obj-C wrapper tests
            name: "MyPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackage"]
        )
    ],
    cxxLanguageStandard: .gnucxx1z
)
```

And the directory structure is

```
MyPackage
 |
 .- Sources
 |  |
 |  .- MyPackage
 |  |  |
 |  .  .- Classes (implementation files for Objective-C wrappers)
 |  |  |
 |  |  .- include
 |  |        MyClass.h (Obj-C header)
 |  |
 |  .- MyPackageCPP
 |     |
 |     .- Classes (C++ Implementation files)
 |     |
 |     .- include
 |           MyClassCPP.h (C++ header)
 |           MyPointClass.h (Simple C-header defining a custom struct)
 |
 .- Tests
    |
    .- MyPackageCPPTests
    |     MyPackageCPPTests.mm (XCTestCase-based unit tests for C++ API)
    |
    .- MyPackageTests
          MyPackageTests.mm (XCTestCase-based unit tests for pure Obj-C API)
```

The key header files:

MyPointClass.h (meant to define a simple C type usable by both the C++ class and its Obj-C wrapper):

```
struct MyPoint {
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

MyClassCPP.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "MyPointClass.h"

#include <string>
#include <memory>

class MyClassCPP {

public:
    MyClassCPP() = delete;
    MyClassCPP(const std::string &info);
    ~MyClassCPP();

    bool initialized();
    MyPoint modifyPoint(MyPoint point);


private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr <struct Impl> _pImpl;
};
```

MyClass.h (Obj-C wrapper class)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "MyPointClass.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

// iOS Platform specific implementation

@interface MyClass : NSObject

-(instancetype)initWithInfoInAString:(NSString*)someInfoInAString;

-(MyPoint)modifyPoint:(MyPoint)point;

@property (atomic, readonly) BOOL initialized;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**The problem**

I've been having problems with the includes. The unit tests work as they are now, but if I change the Obj-C test file from `MyPackageTests.mm` to `MyPackageTests.m`, I get a build failure `'string' not found.`   I understand that Objective-C++  (*.mm) is needed to correctly build objective-C files that use C++, but the direct include chain for MyPackageTests does not include any C++.  Rather, it appears from the error that, when building module the Obj-C `MyPackage`, *all* of the header files from the C++ package `MyPackageCPP` are included, even though only the C header `MyPointClass.h` is explicitly included by the Obj-C MyPackage (via the `#import "MyClass.h"`) (The clue being "`In file included from <module-includes>`")

I get the same build error when I try to include the Obj-C module into a simple Objective-C test app `MyApp` that imports the Obj-C wrapper `MyPackage`:

```
While building module 'MyPackage' imported from /Users/{user}/TestCode/MyPackage/Tests/MyPackageTests/MyPackageTests.m:3:
While building module 'MyPackageCPP' imported from /Users/{user}/TestCode/MyPackage/Sources/MyPackage/include/MyClass.h:3:
In file included from <module-includes>:1: /Users/{user}/TestCode/MyPackage/Sources/MyPackageCPP/include/MyClassCPP.h:5:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
```

**The question**

Are *all* of the headers in the C++ package necessarily included in the Obj-C wrapper build?  (I have tried adding `MyClassCPP.h` to the excludes for target MyPackage, to no avail.)  Or is there a way around this that will allow me to include only the pure C-headers from the C++ package, when building the Obj-C wrapper `MyPackage` (while keeping the C++header available for C++ clients)?

Comment: For Swift, your Objective-C headers will have to import only either C or Objective-C headers, and not C++ headers.

Comment: Understood.  I'm not trying to use either the Obj-C or the C++ modules in Swift here, and the single Obj-C header (explicitly) imports only the pure C header ```MyPointClass.h```.  The Obj-C header does not import the C++ header ```MyClassCPP.h``` (either directly, or indirectly via the ```MyPointClass.h``` import)

Comment: You may find [Can I mix Swift with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files) useful, and possibly [Obj-C & Swift interop](https://rderik.com/blog/understanding-objective-c-and-swift-interoperability/).  My own project will likely experience the same issues in the near future.

Comment: @Eljay thanks - I understand the issues in those links, and I've created *frameworks* for using C++ code within Obj-C (and Swift), with no problems as long as I hid all C++ from pure Obj-C callers or Swift callers.  It seems like the issue here is about how Swift Package Manager handles the imports: it looks as though it imports everything (error is "```In file included from <module-includes>```" rather than from a single, specific header.)  If my understanding is correct, then it seems a solution would involve somehow excluding the C++ header from the Obj-C module build.

Answer (score 4):

> is there a way around this that will allow me to include only the pure C-headers from the C++ package, when building the Obj-C wrapper MyPackage (while keeping the C++header available for C++ clients)?

After trying numerous approaches, I found one that works.  These changes were involved:

1. Modify struct file MyPointClass.h as follows (which I renamed here to MyPackageCommonHeaders.h):

   ```
   typedef struct MyPoint {
       double x;
       double y;
   } MyPoint;
   ```
2. Add file MyPackageCommonHeaders.c containing only the following include:

   ```
   #include "../include/MyPackageCommonHeaders.h"
   ```
3. Create a new module just for the shared headers

   ```
   MyPackage
    |
    .- Sources
    |  |
    |  .- MyPackage
    |  |  |
    |  |  .- Classes (implementation files for Objective-C wrappers)
    |  |  |
    |  |  .- include
    |  |        MyClass.h (Obj-C header)
    |  |
    |  .- MyPackageCommonHeaders  // NEW MODULE
    |  |  |
    |  |  .- Classes (C++ Implementation files)
    |  |        MyPackageCommonHeaders.c // NEW FILE
    |  |  |
    |  |  .- include
    |  |        MyPackageCommonHeaders.h (Simple C-header)
    |  |
    |  .- MyPackageCPP
    |     |
    |     .- Classes (C++ Implementation files)
    |     |
    |     .- include
    |               MyClassCPP.h (C++ header)
    |
    .- Tests
       |
       .- MyPackageCPPTests
       |     MyPackageCPPTests.mm (XCTestCase-based unit tests for C++ API)
       |
       .- MyPackageTests
             MyPackageTests.m (XCTestCase-based unit tests for pure Obj-C API)
   ```

(Notice that MyPackageTests.m is no longer Obj-C++, which was my orginal goal)

3. Modify Package.swift to include the new module, as list it as a dependency for the C++ and Obj-C API mmodules:

   ```
   import PackageDescription

   let package = Package(
       name: "MyPackage",
       platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
       products: [
           .library(name: "MyPackageCommonHeaders", targets: ["MyPackageCommonHeaders"]),
           .library(name: "MyPackageCPP", targets: ["MyPackageCPP"]),
           .library(name: "MyPackage", targets: ["MyPackage"]),
       ],
       targets: [
           .target(
               name: "MyPackageCPP",
               dependencies: ["MyPackageCommonHeaders"],
               path: "Sources/MyPackageCPP",
               publicHeadersPath: "include"
           ),
           .target(
               name: "MyPackage",
               dependencies: ["MyPackageCPP", "MyPackageCommonHeaders"],
               path: "Sources/MyPackage",
               exclude: [
                   "Info.plist",
               ],
               publicHeadersPath: "include"
           ),
           .testTarget( // C++ tests
               name: "MyPackageCPPTests",
               dependencies: ["MyPackageCPP"]
           ),
           .testTarget( // Obj-C wrapper tests
               name: "MyPackageTests",
               dependencies: ["MyPackage"]
           )
       ],
       cxxLanguageStandard: .gnucxx1z
   )
   ```

With this, I am able to create an pacakage that supports  a C++ API, and an pure Obj-C wrapper API that uses the C++ code.  Note that the Obj-C wrapper *does not* force promotion of Obj-C callers to Obj-C++.  A key part of this is that a simple C-struct (MyPoint) is available to *both* APIs, so that the the Obj-C wrapper doesn't have to translate; i.e., the Obj-C wrapper can return the same object it gets from its wrapped C++ methods.