# Can you use metal shader language in a C project?

Tags: c, gpu, metal

Hi just wanted to ask if it's possible to use Apple's metal shader language from C? Apple seems to have swift only documentation, but I thought I'd ask in case I'm (hopefully) wrong.

If anyone has done this before, could you describe how or link any example projects?

Thanks

Comment: Your choices are swift or objective-C.

Comment: Not really. There is metal-cpp though, which is an official C++ alternative

Comment: I mean, if you are compiling C for any Apple platforms, you can use Objective-C

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files) out for compiling Swift and C and etc.