# Delegate - Objective-C callback from C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, delegates, objective-c++

I would like to be able to:

**(1)** initialize a C++ class from Objective-C
**(2)** call C++ function from Objective-C
**(3)** have the C++ class call a function in Objective-C (callback/delegate pattern)

**(1)** and **(2)** have already been implementing using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334547/how-to-use-the-same-c-code-for-android-and-ios).  However, I'm unable to implement **(3)**.

I'm creating an objective-C library for iOS that also wraps and takes advantage of a C++ library.  I'm able to call C++ functions from the objective-C side; however, I'm trying to make a callback using delegation pattern from the C++ side to objective-C++.  The idea here is to not push code from the C++ library into Objective-C++, but keep them separate so the original code is minimally changed.  This is to say, I've already made the bridge from objective-C -> objective-C++ -> C++, but haven't implemented the callback from C++ -> objective-C++ where I can easily interact with objective-C.

Looking for a simple example of this.  I'm trying to use delegate pattern or possibly blocking.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Objective-C++. So everything that interfaces between ObjC and C++ needs to be in a .mm file, not regular .m or .cpp. However, you can keep stuff out of the headers to make it usable for pure C++/ObjC callers.

To call back an ObjC method (there are no functions in ObjC, it only has C functions) you need to use ObjC++ as well, it's simply the reverse of how you call C++ from ObjC:

FooShouldCallObjCFromCpp.h

```
class FooShouldCallObjCFromCpp
{
public:
    void CallObjC();

protected:
    struct NSString* mObjCString;  // ObjC classes look just like forward-declared C structs.
};
```

FooShouldCallObjCFromCpp.mm

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void FooShouldCallObjCFromCpp::CallObjC()
{
    [mObjCString appendString: @" foo"];
}
```

You will have to assign the initial value of the mObjCString ivar from a .mm file as well. You can also use #if **OBJC** and #if __cplusplus to remove code from the headers that a C++ file or an ObjC file including them mustn't see, but be careful there, as C++ reacts very badly when a method or ivar goes missing, you'll get weird memory corruption. Also be careful with redefining types. `struct NSString*` and `@class NSString` get seen as the same thing by current C++ compilers, but other stuff may get mistaken to be different types and then lead to link errors.