# Xamarin.Form load dependencies dlls to apk and ipa

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

- I am implementing a Xamarin Forms solution which has the Shared logic as a .NET Standard **project => A**.
- I have some separate logic in another .NET Standard => **B** which is referenced by **project A** and **project B** has couple of C++ dlls as dependencies.
- The solution builds fine and when I run inside the android simulator, it crashes while executing logic in **Project B**, getting **Dllnotfoundexception** for one of the C++ libraries.
- I have all the dlls inside the bin folder.
- So what is the right way to compile these dlls into the Android apk and iOS ipa to avoid this types of exceptions.
- Taking into consideration, I can't build them natively for Android or iOS.

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334547/how-to-use-the-same-c-code-for-android-and-ios

Comment: As I mentioned, this isn't possible. Dlls are huge and I don't have their code so it means I can't rebuild them for specific environments or write a wrapper for other environments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the right DLLs from the 3rd party and everything worked fine.