# Writing a package that's compatable with IOS and Android for BLE Support

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter

We need to write a library, that can be supported by IOS and Android for BLE capabilities. Ideally something that can be used by both.

Basically, this library will be used by the end customer, to write their own apps to communicate with our BLE devices via sending requests like 0x71, 0x72, and our device will respond accordingly.

However, we do not wish to expose the actual requests to the customers, hence the need for a library.

So ideally they would write code like.. BLEItem.Start() and the library would send 0x10, and our device would turn on.

Just really hoping someone has suggestions. We really wanna simplify things for us and the customers too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the same C++ code for Android and iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334547/how-to-use-the-same-c-code-for-android-and-ios)

Comment: ... see `/hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/bluetooth.h` of the `NDK`.

Comment: The two platforms have different approaches to Bluetooth.  You will probably need to create two different libraries that expose the same interface to the programmer.