# What programming language(s) does both iOS and Android support?

Tags: android, ios, operating-system, programming-languages

I want to make a mobile app, but I app very new to the field. I am looking for what language I should go for. I know that iOS supports Swift and Objective-C. Android supports a range of languages, but Kotlin or Java are best. However, it *seems* that C# is supported on both iOS and Android (but I can't find a solid statement). I am also open to (free) converters. In terms of the app, I have these requirements:

- Make HTTP/HTTPS requests
- Text rendering
- Basic Audio Capabilities
- Image Rendering
- Buttons (optional)

What would be the optimal language? I don't want an opinion as much as I want a simple list. If there is no such language that supports both systems, what would be the easiest two languages to port between? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've not used it myself, but something called [dart](https://dart.dev/multiplatform-apps) could be one possibility for the cross-platform development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, there are 3 popular options, with widespread use and community support:

1. [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) framework (uses Dart)
2. [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) (uses JS)
3. [Kotlin Multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html) (business logic in Kotlin, UI can be drawn natively for the platform)

If you're still not satisfied with these frameworks, other options would be:

1. [Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/xamarin) (uses .NET/C#)
2. [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) (uses JS)

Comment: It seems that across all answers, flutter is the best!

Comment: @SimplyDev if you've accepted the answer that has suggested _only_ Flutter, you haven't understood the point. Flutter is not the best.

Comment: Yes, I have accepted your answer. But I concluded to that because across all answers, Flutter was the common one. It was a bad choice on words to say 'best', I simply meant it was the most agreed one.

Comment: @SimplyDev even React Native is almost as popular as Flutter, but both have important differences. Understanding the use case and target audience becomes crucial before settling on one (unless it's a pet programming project)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, speaking of React Native, I have a question; From what I know, React or other variants(React Native) are usually for web development. Are you using a converter or does React Native naturally support mobile apps?

Comment: @SimplyDev [here](https://www.akveo.com/blog/how-does-react-native-work) is a good article on this. It basically uses a 'bridge' to natively render the JavaScript components.

Answer (score 3):

Let prefer **Flutter** framework (Dart language), by Google. It is quite similar with web development but support multi platforms.

https://flutter.dev/

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it right now! Also, I am not accepting your answer yet as I don't want to close it yet.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to use `c++` both for Android and iOS.

Meanwhile most of the code can be shared between different platforms, there could be platform specific differences; like hardware accelerated graphics, permission handling or file handling.

Starting points:

- [Share a library among platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334547/how-to-use-the-same-c-code-for-android-and-ios)
- [Microsoft learn for cross platform app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cross-platform/visual-cpp-for-cross-platform-mobile-development?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 1):

There are two good cross platforms for developing application on both `ios` and `android`

- Flutter
- KMM (kotlin multiplateform mobile)

Flutter uses `dart language` and KMM uses `Kotlin language` for development.

flutter is evolving rapidly while KMM is getting attraction of developers after the release of android jetpack compose.

Comment: Thanks, I’m looking into flutter!